# Finding Laurent series of this function

Tags: complex-analysis, laurent-series

I need to find the Laurent series and find the region of convergence for:
\begin{equation}
\frac{2z+i}{z(z+i)}
\end{equation}
About point $z=i$, which I've split into partial fractions to get:
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{z+i}
\end{equation}
But I'm unsure on how to apply the definition of a Laurent series to obtain it for this equation at $z=i$.

Comment: Since those two don't have poles at $i$, it is the same as the taylor-maclaurin series at $i$ (for that reason I am wondering if you might mean at $z=-i$ if this is an exercise that's suppose to get you comfortable with the pole part of a Laurent series)

Comment: @TokenToucan I think this is just basic Laurent series practice (it's a follow on question from a MacLaurin series question), the question definitely says about point $z=i$

Answer (score 1):

You should rewrite both of the terms such that they can be expressed as a geometric series. For $\frac{1}{z+\mathrm i}$ this would be

$$\frac{1}{z+\mathrm i}=\frac{1}{2\mathrm i +(z-\mathrm i)}=\frac{1}{2\mathrm i}\frac{1}{1-\frac{\mathrm i}{2}(z-\mathrm i)}.$$

Then use the known formula

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty q^k=\frac{1}{1-q}$$

for $\vert q\vert<1$. The other term works similarly.

Comment: I don't think your first expression is correct, although the idea is right.

Comment: The OP ask for series around $i$

Comment: Corrected both issues, thanks!

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Thanks, I understand all the top steps, when using the known formula, do I just substitute $q$ for $\frac{i}{2}(z-i)$?

Comment: @GroupTheory14: Exactly. And from the condition $\vert q\vert<1$ you can also gain information about the region of convergence.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos Thanks so much, I've obtained the first 4 terms as well as it's region of convergence, I'm trying to figure how I can make $\frac{1}{z}$ into the form $\frac{1}{1-z}$, could you possibly give a hint?

Comment: @GroupTheory14: $\frac{1}{z}=\frac{1}{\mathrm i+(z-\mathrm i)}$